`docker build --check .` equivalent in Docker Python SDK?
I'm looking to use the Docker SDK to perform docker build --check ..
But I don't see any option in the docs. Is there a way to "dry run" the Docker build process and surface issues without actually building?

Docker SDK doesn't have a built-in method specifically equivalent to docker build --check, which is used to perform a 'dry run' of a Docker build to check for potential issues without actually building the image.
you need to opt for other options which are not so quick as 'dry run' but can somehow imitate it.

This is because the docker SDK is for interacting with the docker engine/daemon. The --check flag simply causes a lint to be performed, which is performed by the client, and does not interact with the daemon or engine. You will need a different tool if you want to lint the dockerfile.
You can see the lint implementation here and example of calling code.
